# Ring fence CPU for a specific programme / process to stop it using to much

Tags: cpu

I've just had an app run my CPU (as viewed in activity monitor) to 102% whilst it was running a compiling and installation task.

My machine was basically unusable as a result.

Is it possible to ring fence an amount of CPU for a task, so that 
I could say that this application can utilize no more that 50% of CPU power? Presumably it would make the task around twice as long, but at least I would be able to do other stuff whilst the CPU-hungry app is running.

My computer is running macOS 10.12.

Comment: Have a look at `man nice`.

Comment: and, renice for processes already running...

Answer (score 2):

The figure in Activity Monitor is actually listed as 'percentage of one core' [which is why it can go over 100%] so this is going to depend really on how many cores you have.

I have found the simplest way to get the most out of a task like compiling whilst still being able to use the Mac as normal is to run a VM of your OS in something like Parallels - assigning it exactly your **real** core-count [ie half of your count including HyperThreading].
In practise, this will mean it uses one of each hyperthread on each core; giving maximum speed with maximum remaining potential.

Comment: Don't forget that i5 CPUs don't do Hyperthreading, so the actual core count is the actual core count.

Comment: I can’t say I’ve looked into this before, but... there’s got to be a better way to limit respurce usage than a full on VM, that’s adding a ton of overhead!

Comment: Better, perhaps; simpler... works for me. I can run 12 cores at full tilt & still use the machine like it wasn't happening [I have a 12-core Mac Pro [24 with HT], which might help ;)

Comment: @benwiggy most i5s in Macs have hyperthreading.

Comment: @At0mic "Citation required" The essential difference between an i5 and an i7 is that the i7 has hyperthreading.

Comment: @benwiggy i5-2415M and i5-5257M both have 2 cores with hyperthreading.

Comment: If you're not certain you could always compare the number of cores in About this Mac > System Report > Hardware Overview with the number of lines in Activity Monitor > Window>CPU Usage [or History]